# How to properly write a cursor inside a function?

Tags: mysql, function, cursors

I require your help because I'm kind of lost. I tried to look over google for cursors in functions and references about those but I can't seem to quite wrap my head the concept. I have a homework where I need to :

- Create a functions in which I use cursors
- The entry is the percentage of the increase in salary (ex: 5% is 0.05)
- The functions need to update the salary with the new increased price
- Show the new average salary
- And deal with possible errors

This is what i've made so far...

Can you help me out with the problem with hint or at least simple examples/ressources of cursors in functions so get I can start get a better hold of the concept.

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS Program;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION Program(IncSal DECIMAL(3,2))
RETURNS DECIMAL(8,2)
DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE Salaire DECIMAL (8,2);
        DECLARE end BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE CurSalary CURSOR FOR
            SELECT Sala_EMPL
                        FROM EMPLOYE;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET end = TRUE;      

        OPEN CurSalary;
            loop_cursor: LOOP
                IF end THEN 
                    LEAVE loop_cursor; 
                END IF;
                UPDATE EMPLOYE
                SET Sala_EMPL=(Sala_EMPL*IncSal);
            END LOOP;
        CLOSE CurSalary;

        RETURN AVG(CurSalary);
    END; 
    //
    DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a cursor you have to FETCH from the cursor (please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fetch.html) without a fetch the loop is infinite. AVG is an aggregate function , you cannot AVG over a cursor (you need a select..from). Your update statement will apply to all employees every time you iterate a cursor loop (logically absurd). Personally I would never use a function because what you are trying to do is not really appropriate in a function (i would use a procedure).

an example of a 'working' but wrong function

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS f;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION f(IncSal DECIMAL(3,2))
RETURNS DECIMAL(8,2)
DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE Salaire DECIMAL (8,2);
        DECLARE end BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE CurSalary CURSOR FOR
        SELECT salary FROM EMPLOYEe;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET end = TRUE;      

        OPEN CurSalary;
            loop_cursor: LOOP
                 fetch cursalary into salaire;
                IF end THEN 
                    LEAVE loop_cursor; 
                END IF;
                UPDATE EMPLOYEe
                            SET Salary=salary + (salary*incsal);
            END LOOP;
        CLOSE CurSalary;

        #RETURN AVG(CurSalary);
        return (select avg(salary) from employee);
    END; 
    //
    DELIMITER ;

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from employee;
+------------+-----------+--------------+--------+
| employeeid | firstname | departmentid | salary |
+------------+-----------+--------------+--------+
|          1 | aaa       |            1 |  10000 |
|          2 | bbb       |            2 |  10000 |
|          3 | ccc       |            3 |  10000 |
+------------+-----------+--------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]>     select f(.05);
+----------+
| f(.05)   |
+----------+
| 11576.00 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]>     select * from employee;
+------------+-----------+--------------+--------+
| employeeid | firstname | departmentid | salary |
+------------+-----------+--------------+--------+
|          1 | aaa       |            1 |  11576 |
|          2 | bbb       |            2 |  11576 |
|          3 | ccc       |            3 |  11576 |
+------------+-----------+--------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm slowly but surely getting a hold on these concepts, really appreciated!